# matlab error matrix dimension must agree

Tags: matlab

i am attempting to debug a part of the code but getting this error:

```
??? Error using ==> plus
```

Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> dwtembed at 48
        cH1=cH1+k*pn_sequence_h;

This is the code segment:

```
for kk=1:length(message_vector)  
pn_sequence_h=round(2*(rand(Mc/2,Nc/2)-0.5)); 
pn_sequence_v=round(2*(rand(Mc/2,Nc/2)-0.5)); 
if (message(kk) == 0) 
    cH1=cH1+k*pn_sequence_h; 
    cV1=cV1+k*pn_sequence_v; 
end 
end
```

These are the values for the variables:

```
kk 18096  
message_vector <150096x1 double>  
pn_sequence_h <118x116 double>  
Mc 236  
Nc 232  
pn_sequence_v <118x116 double>  
cH1 <118x116x3 double>  
cV1 <118x116x3 double>  
k   2
```

Can you please help me out with the information provided.

Comment: You are trying to sum a `3D matrix (118x116x3)` with a `2D matrix 118x116`. That's why you get the error above.

Comment: how should i convert both into a 2D matrix?what changes should i make in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatch dimensions. You are trying to add `CH1` of size 118x116x3 (a 3D array) with `on_sequence_h` which is 118x116 (a 2D matrix). This operation is **not defined**

You may use `bsxfun`:

```
cH1 = bsxfun( @plus, cH1, k*pn_sequence_h );
```

Comment: i tried this but i am still getting the same error,what should i do?